# Angular : Navbar Toggle button not working in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

Dropdowns are working fine in web mode but not the navbar toggle in small screen / mobile mode.

This is my code which I copied from codepen to learn. I have installed all necessary packages in VS code for the project but still not able to track down the error.

I have added my code.

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">   
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>sitename</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>  
<body>    
  <app-root></app-root>                
</body>    
</html>
```

nav-bar-component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light shadow-sm bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <svg width="40px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
        style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <g>
            <path
              d="M511.981,118.509c-0.135-2.956-1.892-5.726-4.565-7.04l-159.24-79.62c-3.776-1.887-8.363-0.64-10.664,2.898 L229.916,200.282l-55.413-85.891c-0.796-1.235-1.945-2.264-3.259-2.922l-159.24-79.62C6.582,29.138,0,33.218,0,39.268v79.621 c0,4.581,3.712,8.294,8.294,8.294c4.581,0,8.294-3.712,8.294-.294V52.687l142.652,71.326v335.32L16.587,388.008V154.277   c0-4.581-3.712-8.294-8.294-8.294c-4.581,0-8.294,3.712-8.294,8.294v238.857c0,3.142,1.775,6.013,4.585,7.418l159.24,79.62  c5.427,2.714,12.003-1.375,12.003-7.418V318.087l324.17,162.085c5.427,2.714,12.003-1.375,12.003-7.418V118.888 C512,118.76,511.987,118.636,511.981,118.509z M175.827,299.541v-152.5l145.239,225.12L175.827,299.541z M495.413,459.335
  l-139.34-69.671l108.576-186.993c2.299-3.961,0.952-9.037-3.009-11.337c-3.96-2.298-9.036-0.953-11.337,3.009L344.094,377.258
  L239.77,215.555L347.383,49.998l144.717,72.359l-26.387,45.446c-2.299,3.961-0.952,9.037,3.009,11.337    c3.958,2.297,9.035,0.953,11.337-3.009l15.354-26.443V459.335z"
              fill="#000" />
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
      <span class="ml-3 font-weight-bold">BRAND</span>
    </a> <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbar4">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar4">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto pl-lg-4">
        <li class="nav-item px-lg-2 active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <span
              class="d-inline-block d-lg-none icon-width"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-lg-2"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="d-inline-block d-lg-none icon-width"><i
                class="fas fa-spa"></i></span>Services</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-lg-2"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="d-inline-block d-lg-none icon-width"><i
                class="far fa-user"></i></span>About</a> </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-lg-2 dropdown d-menu">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"><span class="d-inline-block d-lg-none icon-width"><i
                class="far fa-caret-square-down"></i></span>Dropdown
            <svg id="arrow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
              stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
              <polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu shadow-sm sm-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-lg-2"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="d-inline-block d-lg-none icon-width"><i
                class="far fa-envelope"></i></span>Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-3 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i><span class="d-lg-none ml-3">Twitter</span>
          </a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i><span class="d-lg-none ml-3">Facebook</span>
          </a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i><span class="d-lg-none ml-3">Instagram</span>
          </a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i><span class="d-lg-none ml-3">Linkedin</span>
          </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--The html below this line is for display purpose only-->

<div class="py-5 text-center text-white bg-primary">
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="mx-auto col-lg-10">
        <h1 class="display-4 mb-4 ">This is a beautiful Bootstrap 4 Navbar with Social Media Icons </h1>
        <p class="lead mb-5">There is nothing more rare, nor more beautiful, than a woman being unapologetically
          herself; comfortable in her perfect imperfection. To me, that is the true essence of beauty. </p> <a href="#"
          class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-light mx-1">Take me there</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

nav-bar.component.scss

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
.text-decoration-none{
text-decoration: none!important;
}
/* Font Awesome Icons have variable width. Added fixed width to fix that.*/
.icon-width { width: 2rem;}
```

nav-bar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.scss']
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 991){
    $('.navbar-light .d-menu').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.sm-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(150);
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('.sm-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(120).slideUp(100);
        });
        }
    });
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "827a6af6-728f-4d5f-96bc-943087091b6a"
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/script/script.js"
              
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production" 
              
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:development",
              "sslCert": "ssl/server.crt",
              "sslKey": "ssl/server.key",
              "ssl": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgbModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

styles.scss

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css";
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

[Example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pnaeci)

Comment: Please add navbar component file also.

Comment: Added now @DRASHTIDOBARIYA

Comment: @DRASHTIDOBARIYA have you checked it

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz link with your code?

Comment: Hi, this is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pnaeci, This is the first time I'm using Stackblitz. LEt me know if I need t solve any dependencies

Comment: Did you forget to include style.css code in stackblitz or is it empty in your project as well?

Comment: @DRASHTIDOBARIYA https://github.com/Maanavar/angular here you can find the entire code

Answer (score 0):

I added the following styles and it worked for me

```
body {
  min-height: 75rem;
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue. Angular version 12+, bootstrap version 5+

The issue was, it wasn't picking up the collapse class when navbar icon got clicked so, I had to use a boolean to fix that.
In your navbar button call a click method to set that boolean true/false. Based on the condition, display collapse class. I am sharing the code for understanding the flow and logic.

**filename.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routeLink="/">
      <img src="/assets/brand/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"     
      data-target="#navbarItems" aria-controls="navbarItems"                
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" 
      (click)="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarItems" class.collapse]="navbarCollapsed">
  ...
```

**filename.component.ts**

```
navbarCollapsed = true
```

I hope this works for you!
If any of you still facing the same issue with the aforementioned code then please leave a comment.

Thank you!